# Flutter map a list into object

Tags: sql, sqlite, flutter, dart

Hello I have a Database with Recipes. Those have a title, ingredients ando so on. But now I need to convert the data into a object for my app. But here comes the problem I dont know how I can map a list of things in a Object with flutter. The table with the ingredients has three columns a ingredient id which is unique, a recipe id which refers to a recipe so its not unique and the name of the ingredient. I had a way adding it but than I got the error "Uint8ArrayView' is not a subtype of type 'List" to fix this I used .toString() but this doesnt work for the ingredients. Because its of type List and not od type string.

> What I already got:

```
//...
return Recipe(
      id: i,
      name: parsedTitle[i]['Rezept_Title'].toString(),
      ingredients: //Here is where I need help,
      preperation: parsedPreperation[i]['Zubereitung'].toString(),
      imageUrl: imgUrl[i]['Image_URL'],
    );


//...
```

I hope you can help me. Thank you!

Comment: explain more. the result you have vs the one you want.

Comment: My result now is nothing because I dont know how to put the list into it. What I want is for the object a list of ingredients like: [noodles,sauce,...]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know the json you get from your api but lets say it is

```
[
  {
    "id": 1,
    "name": "Recipe name1",
    "ingredients": [
      {
        "name": "ingredient 1",
        "quantity": "1 tbsp"
      },
      {
        "name": "ingredient 2",
        "quantity": "1 tbsp"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "name": "Recipe name2",
    "ingredients": [
      {
        "name": "ingredient 1",
        "quantity": "1 tbsp"
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

Now, I'll paste the sample json [here on quicktype](https://app.quicktype.io/).

It generates all the required classes for me using the json. Just skip past the code below as it is generated from the site to see the code in action.

---

```dart
// To parse this JSON data, do
//
//     final recipe = recipeFromJson(jsonString);

import 'dart:convert';

List<Recipe> recipeFromJson(String str) => List<Recipe>.from(json.decode(str).map((x) => Recipe.fromJson(x)));

String recipeToJson(List<Recipe> data) => json.encode(List<dynamic>.from(data.map((x) => x.toJson())));

class Recipe {
    Recipe({
        this.id,
        this.name,
        this.ingredients,
    });

    int id;
    String name;
    List<Ingredient> ingredients;

    factory Recipe.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => Recipe(
        id: json["id"] == null ? null : json["id"],
        name: json["name"] == null ? null : json["name"],
        ingredients: json["ingredients"] == null ? null : List<Ingredient>.from(json["ingredients"].map((x) => Ingredient.fromJson(x))),
    );

    Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
        "id": id == null ? null : id,
        "name": name == null ? null : name,
        "ingredients": ingredients == null ? null : List<dynamic>.from(ingredients.map((x) => x.toJson())),
    };
}

class Ingredient {
    Ingredient({
        this.name,
        this.quantity,
    });

    String name;
    String quantity;

    factory Ingredient.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => Ingredient(
        name: json["name"] == null ? null : json["name"],
        quantity: json["quantity"] == null ? null : json["quantity"],
    );

    Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
        "name": name == null ? null : name,
        "quantity": quantity == null ? null : quantity,
    };
}
```

---

**Use:**

Let's say you are using [http](https://pub.dev/packages/http) package to get the json.

```dart
var response = await http.get('your_url_for_json');
var body = response.body;

final recipes = recipeFromJson(body);//the first commented line from the generated code.
```

Now, you can simply use `.` to get all values inside

`recipes.first.id` for id of first entry.
`recipes.first.ingredients.first.name` for name of ingredient of first entry.

Loops also work

```dart
for(var r in recepis){
    print(r.id);
}
```